# Shared Google calendar: how to find who updated event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

My team is using google shared calendar. Sometimes members blow away some events, I would like to see if there is a way to find out 'last updated by' and 'who updated specific event'

I could not find setting in Google calendar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. However, rather than giving users editor rights to the calendar, you could simply give them read or freebusy access to the calendar and configure the calendar to auto-accept the events. Then when users need to create events on the shared calendar, they'd invite the calendar rather than creating the event directly on it. This gives each user access to modify only the events they own on the calendar.